# AVAsset writer stutters in the beginning when recording from camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, recording, avassetwriter

I've been wanting to get rid of an issue I've had for a long time. When I start recording from the camera, it stutters in the beginning. I've delayed the start time in startSession(), but I believe now that isn't the best solution.

My createWriter function code below:

```
func createWriter() {

        print("created writer")

        let fileManagement = FileManagement()
        fileManagement.checkForAndDeleteFile()
        fileManagement.checkForAndDeleteExportFile()

        do {
            assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: fileManagement.movieURL() as URL, fileType: AVFileType.mov)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        var videoWidth:Int = Int(currentVideoDimensions!.height) // note: these are swapped because of REASONS
        let videoHeight:Int = Int(currentVideoDimensions!.width)

        if filterShouldUseFullAspectRatio() == false { // square
            videoWidth = Int(currentVideoDimensions!.width)
        }

        let videoSettings = [
            AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264,
            AVVideoWidthKey : videoWidth,
            AVVideoHeightKey : videoHeight
        ] as [String : Any]

        let assetWriterVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: videoSettings)

        assetWriterVideoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true


        let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary: [String : Any] = [
            String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey) : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
            String(kCVPixelBufferWidthKey) : Int(currentVideoDimensions!.width),
            String(kCVPixelBufferHeightKey) : Int(currentVideoDimensions!.height),
            String(kCVPixelFormatOpenGLESCompatibility) : kCFBooleanTrue!
            ] as [String : Any]

        assetWriterPixelBufferInput = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: assetWriterVideoInput,
                                                                           sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)

        if importedLivePreviewOn {
            currentCaptureMillisecondsTime = currentTimeInMilliSeconds()
        }

        if assetWriter!.canAdd(assetWriterVideoInput) {
            assetWriter!.add(assetWriterVideoInput)
        } else {
            print("no way!!! cannot add \(assetWriterVideoInput)")
        }

}
```

When I call createWriter, check if startWriting() started, and startSession:

```
createWriter()

if let writer = assetWriter {

    if writer.startWriting() {

        videoIsRecording = true

        // delay time of video capture to not include blank frames (black)

        let startingTimeDelay = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.1, preferredTimescale: 1000000000)
        let startTimeToUse = CMTimeAdd(currentSampleTime!, startingTimeDelay)

        assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: startTimeToUse)

        recStartTime = Double(startTimeToUse.value) / Double(startTimeToUse.timescale)

    }

}
```

Appending buffers:

```
if self.videoIsRecording &&
   self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {

    guard let writer: AVAssetWriter = self.assetWriter, writer.status == .writing else {
        return
    }

    let filteredBuffer : CVPixelBuffer? = self.buffer(from: camIMG)

    self.MTLContext?.render(_:camIMG, to:filteredBuffer!)

    let success = self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.append(filteredBuffer!, withPresentationTime: self.currentSampleTime!)

    if success == false {
        print("Pixel Buffer input failed")
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you append buffers? From my previous experience, I would check a buffer's data is ready via `CMSampleBufferDataIsReady` and writer input is ready using `isReadyForMoreMediaData`

Comment: Updated post to show how I append buffers

Comment: I also try to call createWriter() as soon as the currentVideoDimensions become available in captureOutput. But still, when I start recording there's a big 1/4 to 1/2 second pause in the beginning.

Comment: CMSampleBufferDataIsReady has never shown any advantage. I tried again, and I still have the same problem.